# Format products and variations SKU on woocommerce wordpress product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, sku

I want to show only the first 5 digits of the composed SKU for products, here's the context:

Main product SKU: 12345
Variation SKU: 67890

SKU showed on product page:  12345-67890

I want to show only the first (main product) SKU number:

this is what I tried:

```
$sku = $product->get_sku();
$skunodash = substr($sku, 0, 5);
        
<span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU :', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo $skunodash ? $sku: esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>
```

I have also tried:

```
$skunodash = explode("-", $sku)
```

But nothing works, and just shows the whole SKU no matter what.

What am I doing wrong?

Thans in advance.

Comment: Hard to say where it is wrong. Test it as `<span class="sku_wrapper"> aaa <span class="sku"> ...` and `... <?php echo 'bbb' ?></span></span>` if the output will be correct, test again `$sku = $product->get_sku();     $sku = substr($sku,0,5);`

Comment: _"...SKU showed on product page: 12345-67890..."._ By default, the sku of the main product is displayed. When I choose a variant from the drop-down menu, it changes the sku text to the currently selected product. So your question doesn't seem to be a standard behavior in WooCommerce. Could you clarify your question? For example, your does not mention which template file you are adjusting (`single-product/meta.php`) while this kind of information is crucial in your question. Also see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)